# How to enable builtin permalink edit for custom post type?

Tags: wordpress

When editing/creating a post or page the permalink is shown directly under the title field and you can edit it.

Is there a way to activate the same function for a custom post type?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by default. This is how I add my custom post type:

```
register_post_type("oproep", array("labels"     => array("name" => "Oproep", 'singular_name' => "Oproep"),
                                   'public'     => true, 'has_archive' => true));
```

When I create a new post of type oproep, the slug is changeable as soon as i gave my post a title. Also I can change if I edit it later like any other post.

Answer (score 1):

The Permalink Editor depends on the `publicly_queryable` attribute of `register_post_type` and as well on the `rewrite` attribute.

This is by default true in both, which is why @berend solution above works.
It won't appear if you set those attributes to `false`

Which is a classic weirdo behaviour of WordPress, to mix things that have zero relation to each other.
However that is as it is.

If you want the Permalink to *show* in the Edit Post Screen, you must set `publicly_queryable` to true.
That will *not yet allow you to edit it*.
To edit it, you must also set the `rewrite` to true.

If you want the `register_post_type` to set the Post type to non publicly queryable/unrewritable and still want to edit the "permalink" you can add use/add the Slug edit metabox instead.

It is *exactly the same*, just that it is in a metkbox instead of the permalink edit area.

The `rewrite` and `publicly_queryable` have *nothing* to do whatsoever with what we are able to *edit* in that "Permalink" editor, but since WP uses the rewrite to show a pretty link there, it is depending on it.

As said, it is basically the same as the slug editor, *except* what shows in it.
Hierarchical Post Types, where the slug stays the slug of the *single post*, but the "Permalink" will be site.com/parent/child, will show that url in the permalink editor, not in the slug editor.

*child* in this case is the slug of the post. *parent* is the slug of the parent.

Again, you can *only edit the slug* in both editors, but for cumbersome reasons WP thinks to know better and does not allow to edit the permalink if you do not set those attributes to true.