# how add permalink section to edit page of posts of custom post type in admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I maked a custom post called **arz-countrydetails** by this code:

```
register_post_type( 'arz-countrydetails',[
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui'=> true,
        'show_in_menu'=> 'countrydetailsSlug',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'regulation'),
        'has_archive' => 'regulation',

    ]);
```

now when I open edit page of post of this custom post in admin section there is not any permalink section in it.

I want to know how to add permalink section to edit page of posts of custom post in admin ?

this is current view of my custom post edit page:
[image]

and this is what I want to add to my custom post edit page:
[image]

**edit**:
screenshot of custom-post screen options:
[image]

Comment: It would only show that field/option if you have it opened by activating (checking the checkbox) in `Scree Options` at top in admin panel while you are in edit screen. It is just not activated right now.

Comment: let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @divy3993 there was not any box in screen options to show permalink.

Comment: @saeidezzati can you post screenshot of the "Screen Options" for the custom post type?

Comment: @zipkundan ok. posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable builtin permalink edit for custom post type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757260/how-to-enable-builtin-permalink-edit-for-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to have control of the permalink, you should make the post type public.

```
'public' => true
```

Let me know if it does the trick and good luck!

Comment: I found also the `publicly_queryable` must be `true`